# Vim arrow brackets all facing right

Tags: vim

This is a bizarre problem that, from searching relentlessly, appears I'm the only one in the known universe to have.

On my Ubuntu 18.04 server I'm trying to do some HTML edits with vim, but regardless of if I type "<" or ">" in vim they all come out like ">".

I'm at a complete loss here, I've never seen vim bug out on me so badly.

Comment: Check `:imap` to see if you have some strange insert mode mapping set on `<`, perhaps from a buggy autoclose plugin?

Comment: in vim I typed :imap and below is the output. I've no clue what it means.

i  <C-U>*      * <C-G>u<C-U>*

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with Digital Ocean's Web console, not VIM. There's currently no solution. Sorry to bother the VIM community with this issue.